# Change value in UITextField from PopOver UITableViewCell selection in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, popover

I have an `iOS` Xcode7 `Swift2` project I'm working on.  I have an `AddViewController` that has a `UITextField` with a `UIButton` next to is.  When it is pressed it brings a new `PopOverViewController`.

The code to initiate the `PopOver` is:

```
    let bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let center = bounds.width/2

    var popoverContent = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PopOverViewController"))! as UIViewController
    var nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: popoverContent)
    nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
    var popover = nav.popoverPresentationController
    popoverContent.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(200,115)
    popover!.delegate = self
    popover!.sourceView = self.view
    popover!.sourceRect = CGRectMake(center,140,0,0)

    self.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Then I see the `PopOverViewController`as shown in this photo:

[image]

The new `PopOverViewController` has a `UITableView` in it. I want it so when the user selects a folder in the `UITableView`, it changes the name from 'General' in this case to the selected 'Misc' in the original `AddViewController`. How do I do this?

I have tried in the `PopOverViewController` `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
let selected = selectableFolders[indexPath.row]
selectedFolder = selected

let priorViewController: AddViewController()
priorViewController.folderName.text = selectedFolder
```

This doesn't work however.  Can someone please help me? Thank you!

Comment: try using closure or delegate in this case....

Comment: I'm semi new to programming, can you please provide a simple example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let selected = selectableFolders[indexPath.row]
selectedFolder = selected



   [ let priorViewController: AddViewController() ] 

    priorViewController.folderName.text = selectedFolder
```

What i think is that this code does work all there is wrong with it is getting the priorViewController .
You should not create another instance in the enclosed line (let priorViewController:AddViewController()
instead get the view from the app delegate 
this is how i did it in one of my projects 
 let messagesVC =  `(((UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController)as? LoginViewController)?.presentedViewController)?.childViewControllers[1] as? Messages`

```
   messagesVC?.inputToolbar.contentView.textView.text = selected joke!
```

This is all in my didselectrow . plus the code for getting the cell similar to yours.
your view hierarchy might be different , can you show me that hierarchy or just try the above stated  way first .
Note: first try updating the view as you are on same page maybe it's not getting redrawn but i think the first code i gave will solve the problem .